# Replace missing values from a reference dataframe in a pyspark join

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes below

```
Dataframe1 (df_address) - Has 2 columns => user_id and address_id (all addresses for a user)  
Dataframe2 (df_orders) - Has 3 columns => user_id, address_id, order_id (user_id is foreign key)
```

One thing to note is that the `df_address` table contains some addresses that are **not** in `df_orders` table

I need to find order_share associated with each (user_id,address_id) pair which is computed by

`count unique pairs (user_id,address_id) / (address_count based on user_id) * 100`

For that, I did the following

```
df1 = df_address.groupBy('customer_id').count().select('customer_id',(f.col('count')).alias('address_counts')) # get total address counts for each user

df2 = df_orders.groupBy('customer_id','address_id').count().select('customer_id','address_id',f.col('count').alias('order_count')) # get count of each order in `df_orders`

df = df1.join(df2, "customer_id", how='inner')

def get_order_share(order_count,address_counts):
  return (order_count/address_counts)*100

udf_func = udf(get_order_share,FloatType()) 
df = df.withColumn("order_share",udf_func(df.order_count,df.address_counts)) # get the percentage from total
```

The o/p of `df` is

```
|customer_id|address_counts|address_id|order_count|order_share|

|          1|             6|       102|          2|  33.333332|
|          1|             6|       100|          4|  66.666664|
|          1|             6|       103|          1|  16.666666|
|          1|             6|       101|          1|  16.666666|
|          3|             3|       300|          2|  66.666664|
```

However, for the id's that are not in the `df_orders` dataframe, I would like to include them also in the result with `order_count` and `order_share` of 0. I am not sure how to go about this and at what step I need to do this

I am relatively new in PySpark, and would like to know the right way to go about solving this problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit 1 - Added sample data

```
columns1 = ['customer_id','address_id','order_id']

data1 = [
    (1,100,733),(1,100,8389),(1,100,894),(1,100,653),(1,101,649),(1,102,6493),(1,102,6449),(1,103,749),
    (2,200,648),(2,200,545),(2,201,8384),
    (3,300,8392),(3,300,7294),(3,301,828),(3,301,9204),
]


columns2 = ['customer_id','address_id']

data2 = [
    (1,100),(1,101),(1,102),(1,103),(1,104),(1,105),
    (2,200),(2,201),(2,202),
    (3,300),(3,301),(3,302),
]

df_orders = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)
df_address = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)

# Notice addresses 104,105,202 and 302 are missing from `df_orders`
```

Comment: I'm not so sure but I think you want to use left join instead of inner then fill null values with zeros. It would be great if you provide some sample or dummy data to make easier getting a solution

Comment: I added some sample data.  I actually used a left join, but I ended getting duplicate `address_id` columns from both tables Could you please show where and if possible how exactly to use left join?

Comment: Seems like it's solved but try avoid using udf unless necessary. The function for calculating order_share is a simple one you can do it with a simple arithmetic operation in spark.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll definitely keep that in mind. Just to confirm, you mean something like this right
`df = df.withColumn("order_share", 100*(col("order_count")/col("address_counts")))`

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may continue by left join the new `df` on your existing `df_address` and filling the empty values with 0

```py
df = df_address.join(df,['customer_id','address_id'],'left').na.fill(0)
df.show()
```

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|customer_id|address_id|address_counts|order_count|order_share|
+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|          2|       200|             3|          2|  66.666664|
|          3|       300|             3|          2|  66.666664|
|          3|       301|             3|          2|  66.666664|
|          1|       102|             6|          2|  33.333332|
|          3|       302|             0|          0|        0.0|
|          1|       104|             0|          0|        0.0|
|          1|       105|             0|          0|        0.0|
|          2|       201|             3|          1|  33.333332|
|          1|       100|             6|          4|  66.666664|
|          1|       103|             6|          1|  16.666666|
|          1|       101|             6|          1|  16.666666|
|          2|       202|             0|          0|        0.0|
+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I tried left join using just the `address_id` column but it never occurred to me to use the `customer_id` column as well